# Can't add a row to mySQL DB with 'INSERT'

Tags: sql, mysql

When I try `INSERT INTO class('admission', 'class', 'className', 'ofYear') VALUES ('5037', '7', 'mombasa', '2020');`

```
CREATE TABLE student(
    admission CHAR(9)NOT NULL,
    fName CHAR(15)NOT NULL,
    lName CHAR(15)NOT NULL,
    oName CHAR(15),
    dob DATE NOT NULL,
    sex BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(admission)
);
INSERT INTO student('admission', 'fName', 'lName', 'oName', 'dob', 'sex') VALUES
('5037', 'FATUMA', 'JILO', 'ARERO', '2000-06-27', 0);
CREATE TABLE class(
    admission CHAR NOT NULL,
    class INT(1) NOT NULL,
    className CHAR(15),
    ofYear YEAR NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(admission)REFERENCES student(admission),
    CONSTRAINT HKM_class UNIQUE(admission,ofYear)
);
```

localhost gives me an error instead of adding the student to a class. Is there any mistakes or syntax error?

Comment: Note: It is no good idea to use booleans for non-boolean things like the sex. This can lead to unexpected issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. `admission` column doesn't have any number. Therefore `INSERT INTO class('admission', 'class', 'className', 'ofYear') VALUES ('5037', '7', 'mombasa', '2020'` won't be inserted.

```sql
CREATE TABLE class(
    admission CHAR NOT NULL,
```

Change it like this,

```sql
CREATE TABLE class(
    admission CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
```

### full sql code

```sql
# This is an arbitrary db name. 
CREATE DATABASE school;
USE school;

CREATE TABLE student(
    admission CHAR(15)NOT NULL,
    fName CHAR(15)NOT NULL,
    lName CHAR(15)NOT NULL,
    oName CHAR(15),
    dob DATE NOT NULL,
    sex BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(admission)
);
INSERT INTO student(admission, fName, lName, oName, dob, sex) VALUES
('5037', 'FATUMA', 'JILO', 'ARERO', '2000-06-27', 0);
CREATE TABLE class(
    admission CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    class INT(1) NOT NULL,
    className CHAR(15),
    ofYear YEAR NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(admission)REFERENCES student(admission),
    CONSTRAINT HKM_class UNIQUE(admission,ofYear)
);

INSERT INTO class(admission, class, className, ofYear) VALUES ('5037', '7', 'mombasa', '2020');

SELECT * FROM class;
```

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @hosannamwaura I added my code. Try it.

Comment: @ConstantinHong - you r code works because you replaced the single quote character `'` with the back tick. If the field names do not contain any special characters then you can also remove the quotes and use  `INSERT INTO student(admission, fName, lName, oName, dob, sex) VALUES ...`
You mentioned this in your comment but not in your answer

Comment: @Tony, I fixed it! Thank you! Thank you for the syntax advice.

Comment: @hosannamwaura, except syntax errors, `admission CHAR NOT NULL,` prevents adding a row.

Comment: @hosannamwaura - Take a look at the docs for [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html), specifically where it says "An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever you refer to it." and "The identifier quote character is the backtick" not a single quote character as used for strings.

Comment: still dosent work

Comment: I tried the code shown in this answer to create the `student` table and insert a row, it worked. What error are you getting @hosannamwaura?

Comment: @ConstantinHong your code does work, but limiting class.admission to 4 characters will bring an error afterwards because some admisions are long. eg HH 345aa

Comment: INSERT INTO `class` (`admission`, `class`, `className`, `ofYear`) VALUES ('aa 34g', '7', 'mombasa', '2020'); now gives error INSERT INTO `class` (`admission`, `class`, `className`, `ofYear`) VALUES ('aa 34g', '7', 'mombasa', '2020')

Comment: You need to change the admission char in the class table to char(4), and it is more recommended to use varchar. In addition, you can't use'' for table field references, and you need to use `` or nothing.

Comment: i changed char in the class table to char(9) now it works. thank you @ConstantinHong and everyone else for your help